# Multilevel column header as new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe in the following form with a multilevel column header. In this case each Category has a date and a price.

```
       Person  Category1     Category2    
index  Name    Date   Price  Date  Price  
  1    Bob     1999   1      1994  2      
  2    Alice   1992   8      1992  3    
  3    Alice   1994   19     1990  6
```

I would like to transform the first column header i.e. "Person", "Category1", "Category2", etc. into a new column with the name as the values. In addition I want to concatenate the columns with the same header names, to get something like this:

```
index  Name    Date   Price  Category
 1     Bob     1999   1      Category1
 2     Alice   1992   8      Category1       
 3     Alice   1994   19     Category1
 4     Bob     1994   2      Category2
 5     Alice   1992   3      Category2
 6     Alice   1990   6      Category2
```

Tried `reset_index()` to remove the multi-index but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the index of dataframe to the `Name` column then `stack` the dataframe on `level=0` to reshape followed by `rename_axis` and `reset_index`

```
df.set_index(('Person', 'Name')).stack(0)\
  .rename_axis(['Name', 'Category']).reset_index()
```

---

```
    Name   Category  Date  Price
0    Bob  Category1  1999      1
1    Bob  Category2  1994      2
2  Alice  Category1  1992      8
3  Alice  Category2  1992      3
4  Alice  Category1  1994     19
5  Alice  Category2  1990      6
```